# How to execute a function for each cell in a column and loop through all workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, worksheet

Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub TrimColumnD()
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
   Dim c As Range
        For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
            c.Value = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c.Value)
        Next c
   Next ws

End Sub
```

The trim function only works on the cells in the first worksheet.

Comment: Make sure you format your code clearly with proper indents. It's also a good idea to declare your variable together at the top of the sub.

Answer (score 15):

Please change this line:

```
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
```

into this one:

```
For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns("D").Cells
```

In your code internal loop refers to activesheet while it should refer to `ws variable` representing sheet.