# How do I loop through cells and create a new row if it contains a specific string in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through all the cells in column A with content and create a new row above a cell if it contains a specific string. Here is the code I have so far:

```
 Dim rng_cell As Range

    For Each rng_cell In Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))

        If rng_cell.Value = "string" Then
            rng_cell.EntireRow.Insert xlUp
        End If

    Next rng_cell
```

Any idea why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: for a start, try to use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells`. Or do you want to run this on a single column?

Comment: try to write your `for` after this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17243947/vba-excel-how-to-execute-a-function-for-each-cell-in-a-column-and-loop-through

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say your Excel sheet contained the following:

```
   A
1  hello
2  moon
3  rich
4  dells
5  cat
```

The reason your macro wasn't working as desired is because you were successfully creating a new line and then immediately the macro was dropping to the next line and finding the same match, and adding a new empty line, and going to the next line and finding the same match...and on and on.

If we wanted to enter a new line above the line with `rich`, a macro like this might work better:

```
Sub macro1()
    Range("A1").Select

    ' remember the last row that contains a value
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    Dim CurrentRow As Integer
    LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    CurrentRow = 1

    ' keep on incrementing the current row until we are
    ' past the last row
    Do While CurrentRow <= LastRow

        ' if the desired string is found, insert a row above
        ' the current row
        ' That also means, our last row is going to be one more
        ' row down
        ' And that also means, we must double-increment our current
        ' row
        If Range("A" & CurrentRow).Value = "rich" Then
            Range("A" & CurrentRow).EntireRow.Insert xlUp
            LastRow = LastRow + 1
            CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
        End If

        ' put the pointer to the next row we want to evaluate
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

After running this, the output will look like this:

```
   A
1  hello
2  moon
3
4  rich
5  dells
6  cat
```

Give it a try and see how it works for you. Feel free to tweak it for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
  sub Stuff()

   Set rng = sht.UsedRange
    For Each cell In rng
        If cell.value = "text" then
         activesheet.EntireRow.Insert    
        End If
    Next cell
```

I think i might be best for your to just do a loop based on a column if the data is normalized.

Comment: untested feel free to crap on my n00b skills

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Sub test()
    Dim x&
    x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    While x <> 0
        If UCase(Cells(x, "A").Value) = UCase("string") Then
            Rows(x).Insert
        End If
    x = x - 1
    Wend
End Sub
```